# Como implementar getCurrentTimeout En Volley usando el patrón singleton

Tags: java, android, volley, singleton

he visto muchos pero todos son creando nuevas instancias de Volley dentro de Android Studio.

Estoy manejando el patrón singleton para generar una sola instancia, esto significa que la nueva petición que hago por metodo POST sea trabajando esta misma instancia.

Vi que uno de los metodos es:

```
int socketTimeout = 30000;//30 seconds - change to what you want
RetryPolicy policy = new DefaultRetryPolicy(socketTimeout, DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_MAX_RETRIES, DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_BACKOFF_MULT);
request.setRetryPolicy(policy);
mRequestQueue.add(request);
```

Pero ese `request.setRetryPolicy(policy)`viene de un `StringRequestrequest request = new StringRequest(...);`.

Y al trabajar, yo con Singleton lo tengo de la siguiente manera:

```
VolleySingleton.getInstance(getActivity()).addToRequestQueue(
                new StringRequest(
                        Request.Method.POST,
                        url,
                        new Response.Listener<String>() {
                            @Override
                            public void onResponse(String response) {
                                try {
                                    service.setMensaje(service.getResponseEntrega(response));
                                    mostrarAlert(service.getMensaje());

                                } catch (Exception e) {
                                    Log.e("Error Codigo", e.getLocalizedMessage());
                                }
                            }
                        },
                        new Response.ErrorListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Error de servidor: " + error, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
//                                Log.e("Error ", error.getMessage());
                                progressBar.setVisibility(GONE);
                            }
                        }
                ) {
                    @Override
                    protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
                        Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
                        params.put("form", form);
                        params.put("action", tipo);

                        return params;
                    }

                }
        );
```

No creo ese "request" ya que si lo intento me arroja error en el IDE. Alguno ya trabajo con esta parte? Lo que quiero hacer es aumentar el tiempo, ya que al hacer un proceso con el WS me arroja un error "TimeOut".

Comment: Realmente la sintaxis que Android usa para Volley es confusa, yo particularmente me pierdo entre tantos métodos uno dentro del otro..., qué le vamos a hacer. Para más claridad, simplemente hazlo en este orden: 1. crea un objeto del tipo `StringRequest`; 2. aplica a ese objeto el `setRetyPolicy` con el tiempo que quieras; 3. mete la petición a la cola con `addToRequestQueue`. Eso es todo. [Aquí hay un ejemplo más claro de patrón singleton](https://android--examples.blogspot.com/2017/02/android-volley-singleton-pattern-example.html). Si no te funciona, pon cómo lo has intentado y revisamos.

Answer (score 0):

No veo ningun problema, el codigo quedaria algo asi:

```
StringRequest request = new StringRequest(...)

int socketTimeout = 30000;//30 seconds - change to what you want
RetryPolicy policy = new DefaultRetryPolicy(socketTimeout, DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_MAX_RETRIES, DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_BACKOFF_MULT);
request.setRetryPolicy(policy);

VolleySingleton.getInstance(getActivity()).addToRequestQueue(request);
```

Lo unico que hice fue ponerle nombre a tu StringRequest y crearlo fuera del metodo addToReequestQueue para poder aplicarle el setRetryPolicy()